# Notification still in bar after killing Service

Tags: android, service, process, kill

I have interesting issue:

I start my Activity and from this Activity I start my Service in another process.
When the Service is started it shows a notification in the bar.
Notification is with .setOngoing(true), so it will only dissapear only when I stop the Service from my Activity.

Then in Eclipse, in tab Devices I kill my Service-process, but the notification is still exists!
To close it I have to start the Service again and then have to stop it.

> Why is my Notification not killed together with Service?

Comment: Did you find a solution, Azertiy?

Answer (score 1):

So you said that the service is on another process?

Im developing an app with a similar structure. Please Check out the "AbstractService" class and the "ServiceManager" class from package com.philippheckel.service.

[Here are the classes](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~binwiederhier/+junk/android-service-example/files/head:/src/com/philippheckel/service)

[Here an Example](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~binwiederhier/+junk/android-service-example/files/head:/src/com/philippheckel/service/example/)

### So here is how i create the notification

Use the Compat.Builder for Compatibility with older and newer android versions

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.service_header))
        .setContentText("Connect to: http://" + httpd.getip() + ":8080")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setOngoing(true);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(01, mBuilder.build());
```

### So here is how i close/cancel the notification

See that im using the same ID again? this is very important

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(01);
```

Answer (score -1):

R u clearing the notifications at the time of stoping the service

If not clear the notification

just have a look into NotificationManager class to how to clear.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html